# Pagination and Subdirectories

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pagination, subdirectory

I'm having a hard time perfecting the rewrite rules for a subdirectory with pagination.

I have a directory named /files which resides in the root of my website. ex: `www.site.com/files`

The index.php script located in /files displays a list of all possible files if the URL is simply `www.site.com/files`

This is achieved with the following .htaccess script:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?fileid=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

The `/files` directory includes a diretory named `/users`

The `/users/index.php` script will display a list of files specific to a user if a user ID is included in the URL, e.g. `www.site.com/files/user/101`

This is working with an .htaccess file which looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?userid=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

I would like to add pagination to the list of files provided by both of these index.php scripts.

For example if I am showing 25 results per page:

`www.site.com/files/1` would show the first page of all files, one through twenty-five.
`www.site.com/files/2` would show the second page of all files, twenty-six through fifty.

And then the user-specific listings would be:

`www.site.com/files/user/101/1` would show the first page of all files belonging to user 101, one through twenty-five.

`www.site.com/files/user/101/2` would show the second page of all files belonging to user 101, twenty-six through fifty.

Bonus:

www.site.com/files/1 and www.site.com/files/1/ should return the same page.
www.site.com/files/user/101/1 and www.site.com/files/user/101/1/ should return the same page.

Should I be handling this with a single .htaccess file instead of one in the `/files` directory and one in the `/user` directory?

Can someone help me modify the rewrite rules to handle pagination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?pages=$1 [NC]

You can test it [here](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/)